# Assign and Display a Form Value from a Worksheet based on a Match of another form value against a Worksheet Range

Tags: excel, vba, set, match, focus

```
Private Sub invItem_AfterUpdate()
 Dim sh As Worksheet
' Dim ckItem As Long

 Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACS_Report")
With Me
' ckItem = sh.Range("B:B").Value
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sh.Range("B:B"), invItem) = 0 Then 'Checks to see if the scanned value exists.
       
        MsgBox "That Item ID does not exist."
            invItem.SetFocus     *This does not work the focus is not set back to invItem or the form.*
            
            Exit Sub
    End If
    
   iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(invForm.invItem, sh.Range("B:B"), 0) 'Returns the Row number from the worksheet.
   invForm.invUnits = (sh(F) & iRow) *This does not work*
   '  Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.invItem, ACS_Report.Range("Lookup") 2, False)
End With
    
End Sub
```

The entry form has three inputs only two are user inputs. The user would scan the item ID the form would update the Units based upon the scan Input and wait for the user to type or scan in the the real Units I don't have code written for that yet as I haven't been able to get the unit field to update. When it does the real Units needs to add to whatever value is in invReal whether its zero or already has a number. When the entries have been made it updates the spreadsheet and moves back to the beginning of the form for the next inventory update.

Comment: `(sh(F) & iRow)` - did you mean `sh.Range("F" & iRow)`?

Comment: Yes Thank you BigBen that indeed updated the form to the current value

Comment: Probably better to be more explicit too: `sh.Range("F" & iRow).Value`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Vlookup here - you need to pull a value if there's a match, so you can do that in a single call:

```vb
Private Sub invItem_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, m
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACS_Report")
    
    m = Application.VLookup(Me.invItem, sh.Range("B:F"), 5, False) 'no WorksheetFunction
    If Not IsError(m) Then 'check for no match
        Me.invUnits = m
    Else
        MsgBox "Item ID " & Me.invItem & " does not exist."
        invItem.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```